# Is the house Meethi finds in the end, a "real" house or a psychological construct

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, 15-park-avenue

In the movie *15 Park Avenue*, the schizophrenic Meethi (Konkona Sen Sharma) searches for her house in Kolkata, in 15 Park Avenue, a locality that does not exist in Kolkata.

However, the movie shows that she eventually "finds" the house. In the context of movie, does she find a real house, a house that she thinks is hers?

Or is the ending (shown as finding the house) supposed to have some inner psychological significance?

If yes, what is it and how does it relate to the satisfaction she gets in the movie of finding her house?

Comment: Is your question about ending of the movie or about finding the house? Are they two different questions or related questions? Please clarifify. Otherwise, the question could be closed as 'too broad'.

Comment: Did you see the movie ? In the end, she finds the house. Neways, edited the question to clarify furrrrther. :-)